# Firebug hotkey for changing panels

Tags: firebug

Is there a hotkey in Firebug to change between the panels, or some way to keymap this?  Even better would be hotkeys for the console and HTML panels, since I'm looking at those 90% of my time.

**Edit**: for those who have a similar usage, you can hit 'ctrl-shift-l' while in the HTML panel, which will give you a small view of the console.  It's only one line, though. (I think on Apples its cmd-shift-l).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Firebug shortcuts are listed [here](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts).

A nice routine, I find, is to bring up Firebug, switch to from HTML to console, then use shift+` to switch between them.

There is also a [key-binding mechanism](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts).

Comment: I must've overlooked that function when I looked previously, thanks (it's actually ctrl+` in Ubuntu).  I found that `ctrl+shift+pgup/pgdown` switches between panels, but only when the focus is already in Firebug.  Unlike F12 and ctrl+shift+L, it doesn't work when the focus is on Firefox.